# combining and operating on matrices twice nested in a list

Tags: r, data-structures, nested-lists

if `xmpl` is a list where each element has an integer `age` and a list `data`, where `data` contains three matrices of equal size, `a` to `c`

What is the best way to do

```
cor( xmpl[[:]]$data[[:]][c('a','b','c')],  xmpl[[:]]$age)
```

where the results would be `3 x length(a)` array or list that reflects  `age` correlated with each instance of each element of `a` (row 1), `b` (row 2), and `c` (row 3) across  `xmpl`.

---

I am reading in matrices that represent the output of different pipelines. There are 3 of these per subject and a whole lot of subjects. Currently, I've built a list of subjects that has among other things a list of pipeline matrices.

The structure looks like:

```
 str(exmpl)
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ id       : int 5
  ..$ age      : num 10
  ..$ data     :List of 3
  .. ..$ a: num [1:10, 1:10] 0.782 1.113 3.988 0.253 4.118 ...
  .. ..$ b: num [1:10, 1:10] 5.25 5.31 5.28 5.43 5.13 ...
  .. ..$ c: num [1:10, 1:10] 1.19e-05 5.64e-03 7.65e-01 1.65e-03 4.50e-01 ...
  ..$ otherdata: chr "ignorefornow"
  #[...]
```

I want to correlate every element of `a` across all subjects with the age of subjects. Then do the same for `b` and `c` and put the results into a list.

I think I am approaching this in a way that is awkward for R. I'm interested in what the "R way" of storing and retrieving this data would be.

[Data Structure and desired output http://dl.dropbox.com/u/56019781/linked/struct-2012-12-19.svg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/56019781/linked/struct-2012-12-19.svg)

```
library(plyr)

## example structure
xmpl.mat  <- function(){ matrix(runif(100),nrow=10) }
xmpl.list <- function(x){ list(  id=x, age=2*x, data=list(  a=x*xmpl.mat(), b=x+xmpl.mat(), c=xmpl.mat()^x   ), otherdata='ignorefornow' ) }
xmpl      <- lapply( 1:5, xmpl.list )

## extract
ages <- laply(xmpl,'[[','age')
data <- llply(xmpl,'[[','data')

# to get the cor for one set of matrices is easy enough
# though it would be nice to do: a <- xmpl[[:]]$data$a
x.a      <- sapply(data,'[[','a')
x.a.corr <- apply(x.a,1,cor,ages)

# ...

#xmpl.corr   <- list(x.a.corr,x.b.corr,x.c.corr)

# and by loop, not R like?
xmpl.corr<-list()
for (i in 1:length(names(data[[1]])) ){
  x <- sapply(data,'[[',i)
  xmpl.corr[[i]] <- apply(x,1,cor,ages)
}
names(xmpl.corr) <- names(data[[1]])
```

Final output:

```
str(xmpl.corr)
List of 3
 $ a: num [1:100] 0.712 -0.296 0.739 0.8 0.77 ...
 $ b: num [1:100] 0.98 0.997 0.974 0.983 0.992 ...
 $ c: num [1:100] -0.914 -0.399 -0.844 -0.339 -0.571 ..
```

Comment: can you elaborate on  "across all subjects with the age of subjects" .   Also, perhaps a `dput(xmpl)`?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta The object `xmpl` could be created with the provided code.

Comment: whoops!  I missed the part towards the end, my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution. It should be short enough.

```
ages <- sapply(xmpl, "[[", "age")                      # extract ages
data <- sapply(xmpl, function(x) unlist(x[["data"]]))  # combine all matrices
corr <- apply(data, 1, cor, ages)                      # calculate correlations
xmpl.corr <- split(corr, substr(names(corr), 1, 1))    # split the vector
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. Is this a novel use of unlist+split, or is it something I should recognize as idiomatic R?

Comment: @Will For me your task seems quite special. So, the use of `unlist` in this context (transforming multiple matrices to one vector) appears to be unexpected. But the `use` of split here is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of x.a, x.b, x.c  you would probably want to have all of these in one list.

```
# First, get a list of the items in data
      abc  <- names(xmpl[[1]]$data)    # incase variables change in future
names(abc) <- abc   # these are the same names that will be used for the final list. You can use whichever names make sense


## use lapply to keep as list, use sapply to "simplify" the list
x.data.list <- lapply(abc, function(z)
                  sapply(xmpl, function(xm) c(xm$data[[z]])) )

ages <- sapply(xmpl, `[[`, "age")

# Then compute the correlations.  Note that on each element of x.data.list we are apply'ing per row
correlations <- lapply(x.data.list, apply, 1, cor, ages)
```